# Macbook Pro 2012 i7 - Keyboard/trackpad not working in Bootcamp

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows, trackpad, driver

I have a 2012 Macbook Pro 15" Core I7 8gb ram and Nvidia 650M. I have been running bootcamp on it for over a month when last night my keyboard and trackpad stopped working after a reboot. I immediately booted into OSX and was able to use the <kbd>option</kbd> key to do so, they also worked fine in OSX. First thing I did was plug in a flash drive and use the bootcamp util to download the drivers for it. I then rebooted into Windows safe mode and was able to use the keyboard to select safe mode. When it booted it still would not work. I plugged in a USB keyboard and mouse and was able to use those.

I uninstalled all of the Bootcamp software in Windows 7 Ultimate X64 and then reinstalled. When this did not work with version 4 of the software, I went out to the Apple site and downloaded version 5 and tried that as well to no avail. The backlight on the keyboard works but the keyboard itself along with my touchpad do not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does an external mouse work?

Comment: Yes Sorry, my USB mouse and keyboard work fine.